# How to minimize visual flickering with iOS8 "UIVisualEffectView with Blur"

Tags: ios, uivisualeffectview

I have a particular app that, because of the navigation structure, leaves me unable to use normal UINavigationBars with translucency, so I've chosen to try and use iOS8's UIVisualEffectView with Blur.

This solution mostly works, but there is a very noticeable flickering effect that occurs when the UITableView beneath this blur view is scrolled around. As the edges of an image or colored rect pass underneath the blur view, there is a significant amount of flickering that occurs.

Has anyone experienced this? Anyone know how to solve this problem?

My implementation is simple, I dragged a UIVisualEffectView onto my view controller and constrained it to top, left, and right screen bounds, and added a height constraint of 64. Beneath that is just a UITableView with some images and text.

Comment: Blurring is calculation-intensive. It probably isn't meant for this sort of thing. The flickering is probably caused by the delay while the calculation is performed.

Comment: Thanks for the input, Matt -- so you think UIVisualEffectView was just intended for static (without movement) blurring?

Comment: Without a _lot_ of movement, I'd say.

Comment: Hmmm... any alternatives you're aware of? Hoping to avoid implementing *another* 3rd party library.

Comment: How did you end up with this?

Comment: In the case of the navigation bar, the flickering problem was most pronounced at the top of the phone's screen. To keep the blurry effect and mitigate the flickering, I just added a new image view to the navigation bar that is a gradient from dark, near black, to clear. So you can see the blur effect on the bottom of the nav bar, but near the top it fades to black. There's still some flickering, but it helps. You'll just have to play with it. Lots of commercial apps have the flicker, so I just went with it. Apple will fix this eventually hopefully.

Answer (score 1):

> "I assume that what’s not under the view is not being taken into account to compute the blur. It is likely being extrapolated (by padding the image by mirroring, replicating, wrapping, etc… as you would do to minimize boundary effects on any convolution). But this creates an undesired visual jump in many cases.
>
> If you want to minimize this artifact, **just make the
> UIVisualEffectView bigger than your view.** A few pixels will suffice,
> the blurring kernel is not that big anyway. And make your view to clip
> to bounds."
>
> *Reference: https://medium.com/@imho_ios/avoid-artifacts-on-uiblureffect-edges-c30e737c21fb*

This worked for me, at least eliminated the bottom flickering in the Navigation Bar. However, it did not work at the top. I believe that is due to view (maybe UIWindow?) clipping against - in my case - the tableView.

**UPDATE:**
It seems the bug are fixed in iOS 9.0 and later.

Comment: Looks like this is the only way to fix the problem on iOS 8. At least to minimize it.

Comment: Has anyone experimented with how much to pad it? Or know how large the kernel is?

Answer (score 0):

I make an uiview which alpha is 0 and add blurview as subview of that. So i can minimize that flickering problem also can hide/show or rounding corners it with animation.